# PHP create a json response from php to look like stripe api result

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I need to create a json response to look like Stripe API response using PHP.
This is the structure I want to get:

`{ "body": "{\n  \"error\": \"Please enter a valid secret key\",\n}\n", }`

This is the code I have so far:

first I create the array:

```
class Error {

    public $errors = array(
        'body' => array( 'error' => false ),
    );

    if ($this->errors['body']['error'] === false) {
        $this->errors['body']['error'] = 'Please enter a valid secret key'
    }
    
    $resp = json_encode( $this->errors ) 
    echo wp_send_json( $resp );
}
```

but the result I get is:
json_encode result:

```
{"body":{"error":"Please enter a valid secret key"}}
```

echo wp_send_json( $resp ) result:

```
res = "{\"body\":{\"error\":\"Please enter a valid secret key\"}}"
```

I don't want the body to be encoded.
What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you should run `json_encode` twice: first time for `$this->errors['body']` and then for something like `array('body' => $resp)`. For ex., http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c50755d84330a784b1582e319c40a7e5e8a8cbd9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like only the data is `json_encode`d with the error...

```
$this->errors['body'] = json_encode( 
             ['error' => 'Please enter a valid secret key']);
```

This won't have the newlines in it, see if that is a problem.

Or to do this at the end (useful to include that you need this in the question)...

```
$resp = json_encode( $this->errors['body'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );

echo wp_send_json(['data' => $resp]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I need the encode to be at the end of the process. not when I place the error value.

Comment: @DavSev, updated - please make sure any requirements like having to encode at the end are clear in the question as it can easily be missed.

Comment: Thanks for the question edit and the clarification, I have done what you suggested. this is the code I have now: 

`$errors_resp = json_encode( $this->errors['body'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
$resp = [ 'body' => $errors_resp ];
echo wp_send_json( $resp );`

but the echo result is `res = {body: '"{\\"error\\":\\"Please enter a valid secret key\\"}"'}
`. I would expect the result to be :
`res = {body: "{\"error\":\"Please enter a valid secret key\"}"}`

I understand that the error object is encoded twice, how can I solve it? 
`

Comment: This is what I eventually did:

```   $resp['body'] = wp_json_encode(
    [ 'error' => [ 'message' => 'error message' ] ],
    JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
   );

   wp_send_json( $resp );```